# Best way to handle nullable numbers from SOAP proxy objects in Flex/ActionScript

Tags: apache-flex, soap

I'm consuming SOAP services in Flex 3 using the WSDL-generated proxy classes created by the tools in Flex Builder. Several of the SOAP objects have nullable integer properties, which get converted to zero during the SOAP-to-local-object conversion process. We are considering a "magic number" approach, where if the service returns -1, we treat it as null. This is obviously a hack, and may not work in some situations (situations where -1 is a valid #, for example).

Has anyone out there found a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

Flex Soap Encoder changes NaN into Null. Please extend this class and override this behavior.

Comment: I guess Jeff is asking about Flex Soap Decoder behaviour, which is decoding nil/null value into 0.